Conda Virtual Environment Display Issue in Terminal Prompt ~ZSH
I'm experiencing a display issue with my Conda virtual environment in the terminal . The environment name that is rendered strangely on the right side of each line is not correct i expect to show base as it does for virtual Environment .venv but its showing like \$(base), as shown in the screenshot below:

so fat i have tried changing my ~/.zshrc  file and i have updated theme and tried reinitializing
the conda but it didnt work my conda configs for zsh are these:
__conda_setup="$('/Users/myname/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/myname/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/myname/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/myname/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

